# What did I do wrong here? [php]

Tags: php, html, mysql

```php
<?php
function username($uuid) {
   $username = file_get_contents("https://us.mc-api.net/v3/name/$uuid/json");
   $data = json_decode($username, true);
   return $data['name'];
 }
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
             $uuid = $row['UUID'];
             $kills = $row['KILLS'];
             $deaths = $row['DEATHS'];
             echo
             "<tr>
               <td>
                 <img src='http://cravatar.eu/head/$uuid/64.png'/>
                " . username($uuid) . "
               <td>$kills</td>
               <td>$deaths</td>
             </tr>\n";
           }
```

I've recently started learning php for the sake of web leaderboards. I've gotten a working version, although this part is stumping me.

I'm trying to get it after the avatar is displayed it also displays the username that's hooked onto the uuid. The avatar works just not the username section.
Here's a preview of this code: https://gyazo.com/de6f92aa637c0f43f560e4ddfb986a0d
I've googled some common issues but I cannot find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you confirm that `json_decode($username, true)` is really returning you something?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @roullie It's an api so I guess? Whenever I type it into a browser it works.
There are no errors, it's just not displaying the username.

Comment: you need to find out a way of displaying the returned data to see if its an issuewith calling the information or displaying the returned data

Comment: can you try to `print_r($data)` before the `return $data['name']`? and post the result here..

Comment: @gavgrif How would I do that? It works in a browser. Just not sure on how to do it with php.

Comment: what @roullie  just posted

Comment: @roullie '<?php
function username($uuid) {
   $username = file_get_contents("https://us.mc-api.net/v3/name/$uuid/json");
   $data = json_decode($username, true);
   print_r($data)
   return $data['name'];
 }' It says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /home/a3289381/public_html/index.php on line 37. Line 37 is "   return $data['name'];"

Comment: `print_r($data)`  to `print_r($data);` with semi-colon please :)

Comment: @roullie I'm such a nub... Anyways, I don't think it printed anything. [link]https://gyazo.com/5ddc559db20cad563b0a46f481fe5a6e

Comment: That's what i was thinking.. Your `file_get_contents("https://us.mc-api.net/v3/name/$uuid/json");` is not returning anything..  Can you try it with curl?

Comment: @roullie I would, but I don't know what a curl is...

Answer (score 0):

you're not closing the `<td>` that is opened at the start of the row. should it be:

```
          <td>
             <img src='http://cravatar.eu/head/$uuid/64.png'/>
            " . username($uuid) . "</td>
```

Comment: Closed it, although that wasn't the issue.